# Other ways to name buttons?

Tags: javascript, dom, button, naming

I'm following the W3Schools button tutorias. Their example for accordian buttons:

```
<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel" id="panel2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

Instead of having that "Section 2"..I need to be to name that something else on the fly depending on user interaction. When the user makes a selection on a map, an accordion button containing a table will be populated. I need the name to be applied then, not ahead of time... Using javascript, or jQuery, or html.. i'm not picky.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure why all the down votes.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote you a function to add a new section when you click a button - you'd need to pass the values you want in to that function, however - presumably from your user input.

```js
function addSection( section_name, id ){

  var html = '<button class="accordion">' + section_name + '</button>'
    + '<div class="panel" id="panel' + id + '">'
    + '<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>'
    + '</div>'

  document.getElementsByClassName( 'content' )[0].innerHTML += html;

}

document.getElementById( 'add').addEventListener( 'click', function(){
  addSection( 'Section 2', 2 );
});
```

```css
#add {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="add">Add second section</button>

<div class="content">

  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="panel" id="panel1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using ".html('new text goes here');"

If you are unsure how to use jquery to set the attribute, in your case it would be:

$(".accordian").html('new text goes here');

updated, its .html, not .prop

Comment: Use `text()` or `html()` for a `<button>`. `value` has no relevance for display

Comment: Oh thanks, this is for <input type = "button"> thanks for the catch